# VMWare network setup issues with Windows 7 Guest

Tags: networking, windows-7, vmware

I have a Windows 7 enterprise 64 bit host running VMWare 8.0.  I have two guest OSes installed: 1 Ubuntu 11.0 and 1 Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit.  The VMWare networking setup on each guest is identical: Bridged and auto connect.  The Ubuntu guest has a DHCP IP address and the Windows 7 guest has a fixed IP address.

Each guest OS can access the internet with no problems.

Each guest can ping the Host with no problems.

The host can ping the Ubuntu guest with no problems.

The Windows 7 guest can ping the Ubuntu guest.

The Ubuntu guest CANNOT ping the Windows 7 guest.

The host can RDC into the Windows 7 guest.

The host cannot ping the Windows 7 guest nor can the Windows 7 guest set up a 'Home Group' with the host.  The Windows 7 host cannot access the Windows 7 Guest web site either.

From another PC on my network I can ping the Host PC and the Ubuntu Guest.  I cannot ping the Windows 7 guest from the other PC.

I have tried establishing a connection with both Windows 7 firewalls off and still get the same results.

I am sure that the issue is with the Windows 7 guest.  But I cannot seem to find out what it is.

The host list the VM Ware bridge protocol as one of the bindings with the network adapter on the Host.  However, this binding is not listed on the Windows 7 guest.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you allow network discovery?

Comment: This might be something as silly as a subnet issue. Have you double-checked that? Can you get this to work when everything has a static IP address, or DHCP addresses?

Comment: Network discovery is on.  Same behavior with static IP address.  thx

Comment: All on the 192.168.0 subnet with a 255.255.255.0 mask

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following.

1. Shut Down the Windows 7 guest
2. Remove the network adapter from the guest (Windows 7)
3. Reboot the host machine
4. Add a new nic to the windows 7 guest
5. Boot the guest
6. Reinstall the VMWare tools in the guest
7. Reboot the guest
8. Verify firewall is (either off or File and Print sharing turned off)
9. Try accessing via a share from another machine

Answer (score 0):

i think u just need to start the VMware network service

`systemctl start vmware-networks.service`